# nvidia GTS 250 on ubuntu desktop 14.04 Cannot set resolution

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am sort of new to Ubuntu and have an nVidia GTS 250 video card and two monitors: a Samsung and a Dell. In the display setting I have the Samsung show as Samsung monitor and the Dell as unknown. The monitors are the same size, I can without any problem set the Samsung to 1280x1024 but I seem to be stuck on the Dell monitor. I've tried `xrandr` to no avail.

These are the drivers that I have installed (I opened software center click on edit-> software sources and Additional Drivers tab):

[image: Additional Drivers tab]

It seems to me that no matter what I do, I cannot set the right resolution for the Dell, while the Samsung monitor works without a problem.

My Samsung monitor is plugged into DVI via an adapter, where is Dell goes straight into VGA port.

After one of the community users here suggested to switch to proprietary, tested driver I've finally got the right resolution, but now everything is blurred.
here is an example:
[blurred display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z40h9.png)

when I hover over blurred area it becomes sharp and readable.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry wrong post. Hope you get an answer soon!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you specify which is the one using an adaptor and which goes straight to VGA? (now it says both Samsung)  Please [edit] your question and correct.

Comment: Please try switching to the "proprietary tested" driver.

Comment: Fabby, thanks for the sharp eye. the is the Dell that is plugged into VGA and that I cannot set resolution on.

Comment: Android Dev, I switched and it sort of works, but now I everything is blurred until i hover over it.

Comment: So, I found a Fix, switched back to proprietary driver (without tested) edited xorg.conf file by adding proper HorizSync and VertRefresh parameters for 1280x1024

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a fix for this issue. I opened `xorg.conf` file. Found my monitor with "unknown vendor" and set `VertRefresh` and `HorizSync` to the right parameters. After reboot I was able to choose the right resolution for my monitors in display settings.

The setting for 1280x1024 are:

`HorizSync       31 - 81
VertRefresh     56-75`